# Cant update FireBase Database child more than one time

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

I have one button that when you click on it makes an EditText editable, second button sends the new string to the database and the database returns the updated string to the listview.

It works fine the first time I edit but if I want to edit again its update the value in the database but in the app its swiching all the time from the new string to old string in a loop.

[this is my FireBase Database structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y4rn.jpg) (i want to be able to update "_name" for example more than one time)

and this is my adapter: (pay attention to "editTremp" and "submitText" buttons)

```
    public class personalZoneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TrempData>  {

    static class ViewHolderItem{
        private TextView  msg , extra,phone ,date_time ,uid ;
        private EditText name ;
        private ImageButton deleteTremp , editTremp , phoneBtn , submitText ;
        private ImageView sideview;
    }


    private int layoutResource;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public personalZoneAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, ArrayList<TrempData> list) {
        super(context, layoutResource, list);
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = Inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            viewHolder.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
            viewHolder.date_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_date_time);
            viewHolder.msg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_msg);
            viewHolder.extra = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_extra);
            viewHolder.uid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_uid);
            viewHolder.deleteTremp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            viewHolder.editTremp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            viewHolder.phoneBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.phone_btn);
            viewHolder.submitText = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.submitText);
            viewHolder.sideview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final TrempData data = getItem(position);

        //data.setPos(position);
        //int[] androidColors = getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
        //int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];

        if (data != null) {

            if (viewHolder.name != null & viewHolder.phone != null & viewHolder.msg != null & viewHolder.date_time != null & viewHolder.uid != null) {
                viewHolder.name.setText(data.get_name());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._name);
                //name.setTextColor(randomAndroidColor);
                viewHolder.phone.setText(data.get_phone());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._phone);
                viewHolder.date_time.setText(data.get_timestamp());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._timestamp);
                viewHolder.msg.setText(data.get_from() + "--> " + data.get_to() + ", " + data.get_date() + ", " + data.get_time());
                viewHolder.uid.setText(data.get_uid());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._uid);

                viewHolder.editTremp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewHolder.name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(WHITE));
                        viewHolder.name.setEnabled(true);
                        viewHolder.name.setCursorVisible(true);
                        viewHolder.name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        viewHolder.name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        viewHolder.name.requestFocus();

                    }
                });

                viewHolder.submitText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                    if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                        viewHolder.name.setEnabled(false);
                                        String new_name = viewHolder.name.getText().toString();
                                        viewHolder.name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(TRANSPARENT));
                                        viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        data.set_name(new_name);
                                        mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).child("_name").setValue(new_name);
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ עודכן בהצלחה" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


                viewHolder.phoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + data.get_phone()));
                        getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.deleteTremp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                    if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                        mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ נמחק בהצלחה",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ישנה בעיה. אנא נסה שוב",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


                if(data.get_extras().length() == 0) viewHolder.extra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.extra.setText("הערות:" + " " + data.get_extras());

                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(viewHolder.uid.getText())){
                    viewHolder.deleteTremp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.editTremp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.sideview.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255,164,30));
                }
                else{

                    viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.deleteTremp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.editTremp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder. sideview.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(176,176,176));
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of key things going on with your listener set by the 'submitText' button:

```
viewHolder.submitText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                    viewHolder.name.setEnabled(false);
                                    String new_name = viewHolder.name.getText().toString();
                                    viewHolder.name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(TRANSPARENT));
                                    viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    data.set_name(new_name);
                                    mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).child("_name").setValue(new_name);
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ עודכן בהצלחה" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

The first is that each time you click the button, a new listener is being added. The previous listener isn't being removed, you've now got two. Ideally you would add a listener once somewhere in your setup phase and the button would just be triggering updates, which the listener reacts to.

The second thing is that this listener is added to `mDatabase`, any change to any entry included in `mDatabase` will trigger this listener. Within the listener there is also a line `mDatabase......setValue(new_name);`. This is a recipe for weird looping behaviour; the listener is itself making changes to the thing it's listening for changes to...and loop.

So what you need to do is rethink the flow a bit and separate out things that don't belong in the listener. The listener is added once during setup and is ready to react to new data and update the UI. The button just needs to send the new data to the database.

Comment: when you say "listener" you mean to OnclickListener or the mDatabase.addValueEventListener?

Comment: Thank you! It works.. i rethink about the flow of  things as you say and all i did is to delete the mDatabase.addValueEventListener.